# Specifying precision and scale for xs:decimal type and adding an inferred type

Tags: sql-server

I want to specify the precision and scale for my `xs:decimal` and to add an xml inferred type for selective XML index. I don't know how to modify the following script.

```
  CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX [selective_ind] ON [dbo].[xmls_tb]
  (
   [xml2]
  )
  FOR
  (
   ...
       ChildTag1 = '/Root/ParentTag/ChildTag1/text()' AS XQUERY 'xs:double',
       ChildTag2 = '/Root/ParentTag/ChildTag2/text()' AS XQUERY 'xs:decimal(30,5)' 
       ...
  )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
  GO
```